# Untracked files lost after git stash, working on branch and stash pop

Tags: git, git-stash

Please understand the scenario:
1. created a new branch a day ago and pushed my work there.
2. worked on sublime whole day, modified existing files, created some new files.
3. Didn't add or commit, but stashed, switched to another branch, commited there and popped the stash
Whoa !! new files (untracked files) lost

Is this the normal behaviour of stash or I might get this data back.

Any help would be appreciated.
Thanks :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Please use the -u option when you create your stash. Take a look on https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-stash.html

Answer (score 6):

You can include untracked files when stashing, e.g., using the `-u` parameter, as mentioned already.

Just be aware, that untracked files do not show up when using just
`git stash show <stash>`.  For that, you also need to include `-u`, just like when you stashed: `git stash show -u <stash>`

Comment: > untracked files do not show up when using git stash show

If only I read this a few minutes ago....would've saved me from a minor panic attack lol

Comment: untracked stashed files do show up if you add `-u`, which you had to specify to stash them in the first place.. so `git stash show -u <stash>` A quick look at `git help stash` shows `-u` as the first option to `show`  @kerner1000 @Harshith Thota

Answer (score 2):

In step 3, you say you '... switched to another branch, committed there and popped the stash'. The only thing I can think of is, when you switched to the other branch, you committed the new files there, then switched back to your previous branch (where you were in step 2), popped the stash, and saw the new files were gone. In this case, the new files have been committed in the new branch you switched to in step 3, so you'll find them there.

Comment: i faced the same issue! and i did `git merge branch3` to get that untracked file after `git pop` or `git stash apply`